# Asterisk character in expression language

Tags: jsf, el

I'm learning about Java Server Faces (JSF) and Expression Language syntax, and now I've found something new. The code looks familiar to this:

```
<tag attr="#{msg['msg.src']}*">
```

Everything is clear except **the asterisk character (*)**; I didn't find anything about this syntax on the site, neither on Google. Do someone know what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return(or print) the * character after with the message from the properties file.

In JSF el you can mix and match normal string along with the el-evaluation.

In your case, it will print the message and then *

Comment: I thought it is something like asterisk in RegEx... That was one of the last things I would ever think! So simple, so good... :D